# Java Error JInternalFrame on the next showing

Tags: java, swing, illegalargumentexception, jinternalframe

I have problem with showing jInternalFrame from another jInternalFrame to JDesktopane, i'm use Netbeans IDE.
First show no problem appears but when the jInternalFrame close with dispose() and want to show again error appears.

This is the error message :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1093)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(JLayeredPane.java:230)
at javax.swing.JDesktopPane.addImpl(JDesktopPane.java:474)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)
at InternalTes.FrameMaster.menuTambahActionPerformed(FrameMaster.java:83)
at InternalTes.FrameMaster.access$000(FrameMaster.java:13)
at InternalTes.FrameMaster$1.actionPerformed(FrameMaster.java:49)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

This is FrameMaster(JInternalFrame) Code :

```
package InternalTes;
/**
 *
 * @author Vikar
 */
public class FrameMaster extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form FrameMaster
 */
public FrameMaster() {
    initComponents();
}

private static FrameMaster instance;
public static FrameMaster getInstance() {
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new FrameMaster();
    }
    return instance;
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    btnShowChild = new javax.swing.JButton();

    btnShowChild.setText("Show");
    btnShowChild.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnShowChildActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(btnShowChild)
            .addContainerGap(336, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(238, 238, 238)
            .addComponent(btnShowChild)
            .addContainerGap(17, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnShowChildActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    FrameChild wd = FrameChild.getInstance();
    if(wd.isVisible()){
       wd.toFront();
    }else {
        Window.jDesktopPane1.add(wd);
        wd.setVisible(true);
    }
}                                          

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnShowChild;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is FrameChild(JInternalFrame) Code :

```
package InternalTes;
/**
 *
 * @author Vikar
 */
public class FrameChild extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form input
 */
public FrameChild() {
    initComponents();
}

private static FrameChild myInstance;
public static FrameChild getInstance() {
    if(myInstance == null){
        myInstance = new FrameChild();
    }
    return myInstance;
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    btnClose = new javax.swing.JButton();

    btnClose.setText("jButton1");
    btnClose.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnCloseActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(311, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(btnClose)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(244, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(btnClose)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnCloseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    dispose();
}                                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnClose;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

For Window(JFrame), I did not include it here because the code just usual `JFrame` & `JDesktoPane` inside. 
Please Master of java programming here please it's support, this problem make me crazy for a half years. My System Information Project stuck only because of this problem, i have no problem for using unbranched `JInternalFrame`.

Comment: Did you try `setClosed(true)` instead of `dispose()`? You might also have to change `if(wd.isVisible())` by `if(!wd.isClosed())`.

Comment: hello, thank you for the advice. I've tried, but FrameChild becomes not appear, please its support. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can either add this line (the child frame stay in memory but will be hidden on 'dispose')

```
private void initComponents() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
...
```

or either add this line (the child frame will be destroyed and recreated all the time)

```
private void btnCloseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    myInstance = null;
    dispose();
}
```

and adapt the method `btnShowChildActionPerformed` to have the right behaviour.